# Prevent Spam by Modify Events Java.NIO.WatchService

Tags: java, debian, posix, watchservice, java-nio

I am currently working on an application which deals with the Java.NIO-API, in particular the WatchService. My problem now is that the application is being deployed on debian 9 systems which still work with the ENTRY_MODIFY event (this is not the case anymore in debian 12 at least for my use case).

When in use the application captures several modify events with intervals of 1-3ms (filesize 0 then 200...) but I just need the last one with the final filesize of the modified file. Is there any possibility to take care of this problem?

I already tried thinking through the scenario and it seems really complex to me so I figured it would be a good idea to ask y'all.

Thanks in advance.
Cheers